# Minecraft - How to set spawnpoint to a player standing on a gold block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a parkour map and I wanna know how to set a player's spawnpoint who is standing on a gold block. If you could tell me that would be very helpful!

P.S. If this involves a redstone timer then could you please tell me how to make the fastest one?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Probably it would be better to user a pressure plate or some kind of button to activate the command block. If you have several redstone clocks the server needs many resources!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run on a clock:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block 0 spawnpoint @p ~ ~ ~
```